# TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined error

Tags: api, url, google-apps-script, google-sheets, instagram-api

I have written the code:

```
function getId(username) {
  var infoUrl = "https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?context=user&count=0&query=" + username
  return parseInt(fetch(infoUrl)['users']);
}

function fetch(url) {
  var ignoreError = {
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, ignoreError).getContentText();
  var data = console.log(source);
  return data;
 }
```

To get the userID of the username input.
The error corresponds to the line:

```
return parseInt(fetch(infoUrl)['users']);
```

I have tried differnt things but I cant get it to work. The url leads to a page looking like this:

```
{"users": [{"position": 0, "user": {"pk": "44173477683", "username": "mykindofrock", "full_n........
```

Where the numbers 44173477683 after the "pk": are what I am trying to get as an output.

I hope someone can help as I am very out of my depth, but I guess this is how we learn! :)

Comment: `var data = console.log(source);` console.log has no return value, which means the data you are returning is undefined

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski - Do you know how to fix this or where I can look to get an understanding of how to fix this as I have no idea what that section is doing! :)

Comment: @RuanMartinelli it's google apps script not javascript, so what you said is incorrect

Comment: @RuanMartinelli sorry i think that was probably my fault as i believe i put javascript in the tags

Comment: @louisgeorge try to simply return the source instead of returning data variable from the fetch function and it may fix your issue

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski This gave me the error: _Result was not a number._

Comment: that's because it wasn't a number, you only accessed a property users of the response, you said you wanted the number after pk, so you should do `fetch(infoUrl)['users'][0]['user']['pk']`

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised that the endpoint you provided actually led to a JSON file. I would have thought that to access the Instagram API, you would need register a developer account with Facebook etc. Nevertheless, it does return a JSON by visiting in the browser. I suppose that it just shows the publicly available information on each user.

*However, with Apps Script it seems like a different story*. I visited:

```
https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?context=user&count=0&query=user
```

In a browser and chose a random user id. Then I called it from Apps Script with UrlFetchApp:

```js
function test(){
  var username = "username7890543216"
  var infoUrl = "https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?context=user&count=0&query=" + username
  var options = {
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  }
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(infoUrl, options)
  console.log(result.getResponseCode())
}
```

**Which returns a `429` response**. Which is a "Too Many Requests" response. So if I had to guess, I would say that all requests to this unauthenticated endpoint from Apps Script have been blocked. This is why when replacing the `console.log(result.getResponseCode())` with `console.log(result.getContentText())`, you get a load of HTML (not JSON) part of it which says:

```html
<title>
Page Not Found &bull; Instagram
</title>
```

Though maybe its IP based. Try and run this code from your end, unless you get a response code of 200, it is likely that you simply can't access this information from Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `data` to the return value of `console.log(source)` which is `undefined`. So no matter what the data is, you will get undefined.
Another thing to avoid is that `fetch` will not necessarily be hoisted because `fetch` is a built in function to make API calls.